# app engine: get rid of extra lines (Status: 200 content-type: application/json; etc) when running locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a couple of app engine urls that return pure JSON and this works fine in production. However, when I run the app locally (dev_appserver.py), it spits out a few additional lines in the response before the actual json string, like so:

```
Status: 200
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 103480

[{"json":"here"}]
```

The lines before the actual json cause my javascript client to choke, is there a way to prevent the dev_appserver from including those lines?

**edit**: as requested, here's the handler:

```
class GetEvents(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """
    returns json object with events for a given date (yyyy-mm-dd format)
    """
    def get(self):
        start_date = self.request.get("start") 
        use_cache = self.request.get("use_cache")
        # check if we have this date in cache
        output = memcache.get(start_date)
        if output == None or use_cache == "no": 
            # query datastore
            # make dictionary
            # store in cache 
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
        return self.response.out.write(output)
```

Cheers,

the hoff

Comment: please paste the code of the handler (at least the relevant parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, figure it out:
somewhere in the handler, I had a print statement, which seems to cause these extra lines to show up. Leaving this is here reference.

Comment: Yes. You should never ever use `print` in a WSGI App.